error: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError with Mapstruct
I tried to map entity to DTO and receive this exception when debug on getById() method in my TripService Class. This exception occured in line mapper entity to DTO.
line i received when run application
WARN 1444 --- [busTicketManagement] [nio-8080-exec-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Handler dispatch failed: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError]
TripService.java
    public TripDTO getById(int tripId){
        TripDTO tripDto = null;
        Optional<Trip> trip = tripRepository.findById(tripId);

        if (trip.isPresent()){
            tripDto = TripMapper.INSTANCE.entityToDTO(trip.get()); //throw exception here
        }

        return tripDto;
    }

TripApiController.java
@RestController
public class TripApiController {
    TripService tripService;

    public TripApiController(TripService tripService) {
        this.tripService = tripService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/api/trip/{tripId}")
    public ResponseEntity<TripDTO> getById(@PathVariable int tripId) {
        TripDTO trip = tripService.getById(tripId);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(trip, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}

TripMapper.java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface TripMapper {
    TripMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper( TripMapper.class );

    TripDTO entityToDTO(Trip trip);
}

Trip Entity
@Entity
@Table(name = "trip")
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Trip {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "trip_id")
    private int tripId;

    @Column(name = "departure_time", nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime departureTime;

    @Column(name = "arrival_time", nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime arrivalTime;

    @Column(name = "price", nullable = false)
    private float price;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "status", nullable = false)
    private TripStatus status;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "bus_id", nullable = false)
    private Bus bus;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "driver_id", nullable = false)
    private Driver driver;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "controller_id", nullable = false)
    private Controller controller;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "staff_id", nullable = false)
    private Staff staff;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "route_code", referencedColumnName = "code", nullable = false)
    private Route route;
}

TripDTO.java
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TripDTO {
    private int tripId;
    private LocalDateTime departureTime;
    private LocalDateTime arrivalTime;
    private float price;
    private TripStatus status;

    private BusDTO bus;
    private DriverDTO driver;
    private ControllerDTO controller;
    private StaffDTO staff;
    private RouteDTO route;

}

Can anyone explain for me why i receive this exception and give me a solution?
Edit
I didn't receive this any more but i met this Warn Resolved
[org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor]] what does it mean?


Add the full stacktrace you get. You should also have more mappers asyou are using multiple objects as well. Next to that your Mapper usage is also not inline with what you should use when using @Mapper(componentModel = "spring"). You should remove the INSTANCE field and instead inject the mapper. Finally don't use isPresent instead just use map(tripMapper::entityToDto).orElseGet(null) to convert the Optional.

i just know this exception when i debuged and jump into this source:
@Nullable
protected Object doInvoke(Object... args) throws Exception {
.....
catch (InvocationTargetException var9) {
Throwable targetException = var9.getCause();
if (targetException instanceof RuntimeException runtimeException) {
throw runtimeException;
} else if (targetException instanceof Error error) {
throw error; } //throw here
}
I cant copy more because no enough space. Can i ask your solution come from what version of mapstruct?

Don't add code as comments as that is totally unreadable? What code? That is just Java and how to use MapStruct when using Spring as the component model.

Sorry i forgot that. I didn't receive this any more but i met this Warn
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor]]
what does it mean?

Don't add code, config, errors as comments, edit your question. Those things are unreadable. Generally that comes from wrong dependencies due to trying to outsmart the Spring Boot dependency management.

i updated my question. Can you explain for me what this warn mean
